# How to treat a continuous variable in logistic regression that has only a few levels? Ordinal vs continuous

Tags: logistic, ordinal-data, continuous-data

I'm building a logistic regression model, predicting recidivism which is the act of committing a crime after one has been released from prison for a prior criminal deed. One of the variables in the data set is the count of how many times an individual has been recidivistic, the highest number of which is $8$.

I'm considering between treating it as an ordinal value or as a continuous value. The merit of treating it as an ordinal value is, that as the count goes up, the risk of recidivism doesn't always correspond to it, albeit it makes the model marginally less accurate, but I don't feel that using it as a continuous variable would be completely correct either. Is there some middle ground for this?

Since I have up to 20 variables that aren't in English and would need to be translated, here are some hypothetical examples:

$\log \frac{rec}{1-rec}=0.9+3*\text{int367}+0.5*\text{theft}+0.4*\text{drunk driving}-0.2*\text{rec_count}$

vs

$\log \frac{rec}{1-rec}=0.9+3*\text{int367}+0.5*\text{theft}+0.4*\text{drunk driving}+0.9*\text{rec1}-7*\text{rec2}+...+2.4*\text{rec8}$

Where $\text{int367}$ is a binary value indicating whether the individual was interrogated within 1 year of release,

$\text{theft}$ and $\text{drunk driving}$ indicate a categorical variable of the type of crime and

$\text{rec_count}$ and $rec\text{n}$ indicate the number of prior recidivistic incidents.

As a hypothetical mockup this should give an idea of the predicament I find myself in. Any advice would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is precedent for treating the number of prior convictions as a continuous linear predictor. Fox and Weisberg, in an [appendix](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Cox-Regression.pdf) to *An R Companion to Applied Regression*, third edition, present a Cox proportional hazards analysis of the time course of recidivism, with the predictor `prio`, the "number of prior convictions" corresponding to your `rec_count`, treated that way.

If a simple linear association isn't appropriate, one might consider a spline to capture nonlinearity. But as Frank Harrell says in [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms/), 2nd edition, section 2.7.3, "For the case of an ordinal predictor, spline functions are not useful unless there are so many categories that in essence the variable is continuous." Don't know that 8 are enough values to be essentially continuous. He recommends, for more than 3-5 categories:

> it may be reasonable to stratify the data by levels of the variable and to compute summary statistics (e.g., logit proportions for a logistic model) or to examine regression coefficients associated with indicator variables over categories. Then one can attempt to summarize the pattern with a linear or some other simple trend. Later hypothesis tests must take into account this data-driven scoring (by using > 1 d.f., for example).

His [course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf), in the corresponding section, recommend using *k*-1 degrees of freedom in subsequent tests for a *k*-level ordinal predictor evaluated that way. The notes recommend using penalized maximum likelihood estimation (with the R [ordSmooth function](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ordPens)) or Bayesian shrinkage (with the [brms package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=brms)) as even better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider the option to discretize this variable? for example, into 3 categories, when the number of times equals 0, 1, or larger than 2. A more precise discretization can require some domain knowledge how the risks correspond to the number of times an individual has been recidivistic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm assuming that "recidivistic incident" is somehow different from actually "recidivating" otherwise your model is just going in circles - like using the number of times someone was arrested to predict whether they were arrested.

That being said, this is a common challenge in modeling (it doesn't really matter that you are using a logit model, the same issue crops up in other kinds of models and the options for dealing with it are basically the same in all cases). You have basically three options, two of which you have identified. All have strengths and weaknesses and only an understanding of the underlying theory and subject matter can  help you decide which is best for your particular model.

Treating "recidivistic incidents" as a continuous variable preserves all of the distinctions between different numbers of incidents, but it forces the model to assume that the effect of having "one more incident" is the same, regardless of whether you are going from 0 to 1, or 1 to 2 or 8 to 9. If there is something fundamentally different about going from no incidents to one, compared to adding one more if you already have 7, then this is probably a bad assumption, but it really depends on what we know about how "recidivistic incidents" work.

Treating it as a set of dummies, what you call "treating it as ordinal" is a much more flexible approach because it doesn't make this assumption. If "zero" is the omitted category, the model separately compares the effect of having 1 vs 0, 2 vs 0, 3 vs 0 and so on and allows each effect to be different. (unfortunately, it doesn't tell you whether, say, having 6 incidents is different from 5, unless you re-run the model with a different omitted category).  However, if you only have a small number of observations in some of these categories then you may not have enough statistical power to detect differences, even if they are there. If, for example, only 20 people had 7 incidents and 9 people had 8, then those coefficients might not be significant, even though, if you grouped those people together, you would have enough power to say that having "7 or 8" incidents was different from having zero.

This points to the "middle ground"  - "chunking" the variable into a smaller number of categories and then treating it as categorical/ordinal. For example you might split it into 0, 1, 2, and 3 or more. This definitely "throws away information" but if only a small number of people have a lot of incidents then that information wasn't very useful on it's own anyway, but it could still help you figure out whether "3+" incidents is different from zero. IF you go this route, the new categories should be based on both substantive and statistical considerations. If you only have 4 people in the 8 incident category that's a good reason to group it with another category, however, if there is some sort of legal or sociological reason why (say) going from 3 to 4 incidents might be especially important, then you want to preserve that distinction as well.

In short, you have lots of options, none are perfect, because all models are, inevitably, wrong. But you want to find the option that is the most useful for your purpose, given your data and research question.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good answer and yes I should've been clearer with my variable definitions. The dependent variable is whether or not a person might be recidivistic and the independent variable with almost an identical name is how many times before this observation has this person been recidivistic.